# Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!

Tags: feature-request, support, google, firewall

#### UPDATE

Just got off the phone with one of our network guys, it sounds like our credentials are not being attached to the actual call for the JS file from Google.  Since the credentials are not there, the proxy servers are rejecting the call.  Apparently there have been issues in the past in terms of NSFW content coming from Google and there were quite a few grievances from employees/unions/etc. and this had to be done.

The network tech is going to try to allow calls to ajax.googleapis.com to go through and I should be able to test this a bit later...

---

With the recent change with the jQuery files to load from Google (Jeff tweeted about the change yesterday as the jQuery files were the biggest bottleneck the site had), all of the sites in the SO family will not work for me (and quite a few others) while at work.  I believe that my employer has blocked these files from loading from google.  I'm not sure on the justifications behind the block and it will take a while to work through getting that to work.

Is there a way to try to load the google and if the files still isn't loaded to use the functionality that was there before?

This is most likely a feature-request since I know that it was intended to load from Google, but I'm tagging as a bug since it won't work for me.

*I can read posts, add posts/answers...  I cannot vote, comment, or do anything else where the jQuery components are used like the rich text box editing*

**Comments Responses:**
@Cletus - That is a great question...  But as stated above, it'll take some time to sort through and then the politics of unblocking once blocked....

@Chris - Gave that a shot, but it did not work.  I confirmed the IE was able to load the file correctly as well as FF, but it would not load the file as if it were coming from Google for the SO sites.

**Answer Responses:**
@Jeff - I've started the process.  You are preaching to the choir...

Comment: Here's the solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo . Whether or not it gets implemented is beyond me. Also interesting is that Jarrod edited it yesterday, coincidence!?

Comment: This sure seems like a feature to me!  I kid, I kid...

Comment: Why does your employer block Google's jquery?

Comment: That explains why I had to change my NoScript settings.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but could you set your hosts file up so that the api.google.com points to 127.0.0.1 and serve it up from there?

Comment: ajax.googleapis.com that should be

Comment: ..and obviously you'd need a web server locally

Comment: I just completed the webfilter change request process with a government agency.   Just be clear they were not 'blocking' google, they were blocking http://ajax.googleapis.com/.   I bet if this was hosted on the google.com domain it wouldn't even be an issue.

Comment: maybe you need to look at http://careers.stackoverflow.com ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We looked at this, but unfortunately the fallback from failure-to-load-JQuery is quite difficult, as we can no longer use [the standard JQuery ready event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) -- which we use all over the place.

In all honesty, unless this is a really prevalent problem, you're better off trying to get google unblocked.

(Also: who blocks Google? That is a little crazy.)

Comment: Iran blocks Google. And Ahmadinejad *is* a little crazy.

Comment: **@Jeff Atwood:** Why not use a lighter library such as Mootools?

Comment: A large ISP I now of blocked S3 internally a while back. Since it was a large contributor of non work related downloads.

Comment: @Andrew I always thought that mootools was significantly heavier than jQuery.

Comment: **@Macha:** If you includes all the modules, of course it is. But it's the same for jQuery and its plugins.

Comment: I think it's a bit too late to switch to mootools...

Comment: Could it be possible to implement voting with a standard `post` to another page? Adding this option would help in this case.

Comment: @Andrew, the point in switching? Everything works nicely with jQuery! (other than this recent Google thing)

Comment: The problem is not jQuery. The problem is Google, and that Jeff doesn't host jQuery locally on SO in order to save bandwidth. The solution is therefore not switching to Mootools, but hosting jQuery on SO, either with a fallback or not.

Comment: @Eric: Actually, they haven't blocked Google yet. So far, it's mostly been the other way around: Google Code and downloadable stuff (e.g. Chrome) are blocked by Google.

Comment: *who blocks Google? That is a little crazy.* — the upcoming IE9 might block it out of the box when its Tracking Protection is enabled. See [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled).

Comment: @arjan I don't care about that.

Comment: @Jeff, neither do I, but still FYI: Microsoft's "Web Tracking Protection" [has been accepted by W3C](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2011/01/Comment/) for further discussion: *[...] proposes to address information gathering by third parties on the Web through two different mechanisms: A filter that blocks download of third-party content (as is done, for example, through scripts and iframes in HTML), and a global "Do Not Track User Preference".* This might be a very prominent/advertised user setting for the upcoming IE9.

Comment: @Jeff, just in case you're interested for your new creations: [another case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load/184878#184878) where IE 10's tracking protection claimed to have (only) blocked Google Analytics: `SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection. http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`. Still this made SE show *"Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."* Could simply be that IE's message is incomplete, and that IE is actually blocking ALL...

Comment: @JeffAtwood China blocks Google including googleapis.com, but Baidu.com indexes SO.  And logging into a VPN just to get that sweet sweet SO content is pretty annoying, especially since China randomly blocks VPNs through-out the day.  China's mobile phone industry is exploding and already surpassing the US.  I'd like to see SO continue to be a worldwide developer resource/authority.  Please fix this.

Comment: @JeffAtwood _who blocks Google?_ Any privacy-aware human being that does not want to be tracked across the web, I daresay.

Comment: _ready_ events will work if you put the code in <body> instead of <head>. See [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go) and a popular implementation example at https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html

Comment: @fbmd Indeed, ten years after the answer was posted, it seems a little crazy _not_ to block Google.

Comment: SE sites are ***INTENTIONALLY*** allowing google to track users activity thanks to this.  "***who blocks Google? That is a little crazy***" @JeffAtwood do you still believe in your statement?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe switch to Microsoft CDN?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx

I think there are less corporate offices that would block microsoft...

Comment: worth giving a try, as a lot of the questions are about microsoft problem, why not get microsoft to provided some of the band width.  (Provided it is a quick as google.)

Comment: I guess IE9 would not block Microsoft either. (In IE9, Tracking Protection might block Google's CDN; see [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled).)