# What happened to the formatting buttons?

Tags: support, markdown, edits, noscript

When I asked a question on SO, today, I noticed that the formatting buttons that used to be there are missing. What happened to them, and will they be restored soon?

**Edit** Thanks to Eric for pointing out the problem. I use the NoScript plug-in in Firefox to limit the number of scripts that run when I surf the Web. Turns out that, thanks to the changes on the site, I had to allow googleapis.com to get the buttons (and the preview window) back.

Comment: They're present for me.

Comment: Works on my machine!

Comment: I like "Work on my Box" (via Brent Ozar), so that when you submit code to QA you can say it's leaving the womb.

Comment: Ha, thats dirty!!! @joel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're still there...

Perhaps this has something to do with the [Google jQuery switchover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh)?

Comment: See my edit in the question.