# Why does Stack overflow have a syntax error?

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buttons and Preview gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/buttons-and-preview-gone)

I see this when I try and post new questions. I also noticed the button bar is missing and the preview doesn't work...

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: What browser are you using? Which version? On what operating system/platform? Can you reproduce this on another computer and/or in another browser?

Comment: Someone left a stray comment in `prepareEditor()`, which IE is getting very upset about.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome, but verified I have the same issue in Firefox. I think Tim Stone is right and this is related to his link, although I haven't figured out the reason or fix.

Comment: Ok, I don't think it is a duplicate of the "Buttons and Preview", I think it is a pure StackExchange JavaScript error. The reason I think this is a JS bug is that jquery loads fine when I use the Chrome debugger.

Comment: It was a related issue to "Buttons and Preview" - should be fixed now.