# Would Stack Exchange consider moving away from Google services?

Tags: discussion, google

I've been following Google, and their growing pattern of content censorship and manipulation, for a while now. The [recent expose](https://www.projectveritas.com/2019/06/24/insider-blows-whistle-exec-reveals-google-plan-to-prevent-trump-situation-in-2020-on-hidden-cam/) by Project Veritas (more to the point, Youtube's/Google's decision to remove the video from their platform) has convinced me to hard-block all sites related to Google, including ajax.googleapis.com. Stack Exchange relies on Google services for external resources, but I refuse to support Google anymore.  This make it difficult to use SE, which I love.

My question: Will Stack Exchange even consider moving away from Google services? Does the SE organization support companies that censor information and manipulate content? Isn't fighting against ANY form of information control/censorship the entire reason SE was created?

Comment: Do you also block gmail.com, google.com emails? My school's email server is hosted by Google. Probably a good idea to block my school as well.

Comment: SE was created to build a canonical body of knowledge. I don't recall it ever advocated to fight against censorship or information control. Sometimes they take a stand.

Comment: So because one particularly politically motivated organization violated terms of service on another site... stackexchange should suddenly make changes? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, I block everything.  I've always used a browser plugin to block scripts from Youtube and Google, and only enable them if I really need to access the sites.  DuckDuckGo is my search replacement, and I all but deleted my gmail account.  Sometimes it's a pain, but I deal with it.

Comment: @JohnManko So I'm guessing that you either don't see half the emails you get, or you don't realize that you receive emails from Google hosted domains.

Comment: This has come up quite a few times, with regard to china blocking them. it has repeatedly been declined. i suspect a conspiracy theory fueled organization will be just as unlikely to nudge them to make such a change.

Comment: @Mgetz Seems like every tech company is politically motivated anymore.  Facebook, Twitter, Google.  I grew up fighting against censorship.  I don't have to agree with someone to recognize that censorship of their content is a means of thought control.

Comment: @JohnManko as long as companies are made up of people there will be politics, however the violation of terms of service by one particular organization that is not affiliated with stackexchange in any way shape or form does not provide reason to move. China blocking google... that's a much much bigger reason to consider alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh)

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't care about Project Veritas or the content of their video.  It's the censorship of the video (regardless how accurate or inaccurate) by Google that is troubling to the point I will no longer enable their sites.  I'm not the only one.  Even Elon Musk has expressed his distrust of Google.  Google is the new Microsoft, unfortunately.

Comment: _I refuse to support Google anymore_ That's your personal opinion, why should a company refrain from google if you don't like them?  else google is a very good company which hosts many CDN's, maintains android and other things for devs and consumers.

Comment: I think the best way to convince SE to move away from any company you don't support is to make a very compelling business case as to why they should.  It's going to be pretty hard to do when you're not privy to internal business reasoning.  I'm not sure making a political case is all that compelling.

Comment: I was about to post an answer with some arguments on why SE should reduce their use of certain Google services like Google Analytics and their CDN. But then I noticed that your arguing based on Project Veritas, which is pretty much an extreme rightwing fraud based on deceptively editing videos to create a specific narrative. You can't build a reasonable argument on a fundamentally dishonest base.

Comment: "Isn't fighting against ANY form of information control/censorship the entire reason SE was created?" Ahhh, NO....

Comment: This is going to be off-topic, but why "Youtube's/Google's decision to remove the video from their platform" is censorship and a problem for you... *considering we also delete posts on Stack Exchange* and some have protested as [censorship on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=censorship+is%3Aq)?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. The content itself is irrelevant. SE can delete posts they want. It's their platform. Likewise, YT can delete content they want. I'm not demanding for YT to restore content (or laws to force them to do so); I'm pointing out their bias & social engineering, and of doing so in a totalitarian way. Their actions aren't to retain the integrity of the platform, but to control public opinion. They are thought police. It's very scary to someone who values information to develop an informed opinion. So, many of us block google sites, and it would be nice to be able to use SE sans Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Google service that you are referring to is a CDN serving copy of JQuery, a ubiquitous JavaScript library. Stack Exchange is just using that instead of hosting a local copy for efficiency reasons. Google is just being used as a CDN. Anyway, you can safely whitelist the JQuery URL from Google and not worry. Keep Google Analytics blocked because it's invasive and unnecessary, but JQuery is harmless.

If you have a very strong moral objection to using Google for *anything*, including as a static CDN, you could easily write a user script that replaces that domain with another one pointing to JQuery.

Comment: There is reCaptcha, Google Ads and in Jobs they use Google Location services. There is stuff SE are paying Google for. If the OP wants SE to make a point the financing of Google has to stop. Not serving jQuery from their CDN is probably *Meh* to Google.

Comment: @rene I agree, and _I_ have a strong objection to reCaptcha, but all the other domains that OP wants to block are non-vital. Only the JQuery is necessary, and it's harmless.